Issue with Displaying Multiple Subscription Plans in Free Trial Implementation
I'm currently implementing a subscription feature in my app where users get a 3-day free trial and are charged a specific amount once the trial period ends. However, I'm encountering an issue where two subscription plans are being displayed instead of one.
Here's what I've implemented so far:
Free Trial: Users get a 3-day free trial.
Charge After Trial: After the trial period, users are charged an amount (x).
Issue:
Instead of displaying a single plan with the trial period and charge information, my app is showing two different plans.

Questions:
Why might my app be displaying two plans instead of one?
How can I ensure that only one plan is shown with the correct trial and charge details?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!]

Do you code your plan twice? (such as there's is an condition that make you write the plan widget twice). To understanding more, please provide a simple example code that represent your problem, thanks.

@gopelkujo Thanks for the response.
Issue resolved. We can't say this is an issue because Android doesn’t require users to purchase a free trial subscription. It gives users the freedom to choose either a free-trial or core subscription, meaning the decision is entirely up to the user. Therefore, we need to manage our conditions according to the base plans.
